# Create variables during for loop

Tags: r, variables, for-loop

I want to create n variables from a vector of n length

for example if the vector is this:

```
v<-c(1:5)
```

The outcome should be:

```
x1
x2
x3
x4
x5
```

I was thinking about a for loop

```
for (i in 1:length(v)){
  x<-i
  names(x)<-paste(names(x),i)
}
```

but this is not how the names() function works

This is a very simplified example, I know that what I do here is more easy to achieve, but the functions in the for loop are more complex

Thanks!

Comment: what should the variables contain?

Answer (score 4):

Use `assign`:

```
for (i in 1:length(v)) {
    assign(paste0('x', i), i)
}
```